# .Exited event problems

Tags: c#, process

The `.Exited` is not working for all cases, for example: to `C:\foo.png` when I close the responsible application that show the image, I don't get the `MessageBox.Show("exited!");`

here's my code:

```
         public static void TryOpenFile(string filename)
                {
                        Process proc = new Process();
                        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);
                        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                        proc.Exited += (a,b) => { MessageBox.Show("Exited!"); }
                        proc.Start();
                    }
```

how I call the function `TryOpenFile(@"C:\foo.png");`. How to fix this?

Comment: are you positive you closed the application?  do you see it in task manager after you close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you already have your image editing program open?  When you call proc.Start(), if the process is already running, then the existing process is reused.  You should check the return value of proc.Start() to see if this is the case.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326949(v=vs.71).aspx):

> **Return Value**
>
> **true** if a process resource is started; false if no new
> process resource is started (for example, if an existing process is
> reused).
>
> ...
>
> **Remarks**
>
> ...
>
> If the process resource specified by the FileName member of the StartInfo property is
> already running on the computer, no additional process resource is started. Instead, the
> running process resource is reused and **false** is returned.

Comment: Thank you again. :) Is there a more "robust" way to monitor it? maybe checking if the pid still in process list with interval of seconds inside a Thread or a Timer.

Comment: Do you already know what the PID is going to be? If so, you could find it by using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Int32 processId)` and then attach your event handler.